# Unexpected Identifier in Node js beginner program

Tags: node.js

This is a simple code in my main.js

```
/* Hello, World! program in node.js */
console.log("Hello, World!")
```

when i execute $ node main.js 
I get the error unexpected identifier ?

Comment: can share full error...and do you installed node.js on your system.

Comment: I think that $ is unexpected; type just node main.js

Comment: please find the full error below   also i installed node.                            js> $ node main.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:235:25)
at bound (domain.js:287:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
 at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:212:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:551:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:828:14)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to execute the program from within node repl itself, which is wrong. You have to execute node with the program name from the terminal/command prompt/shell not from within node itself.

Starting node alone will run the repl, where you can execute JavaScript commands directly. so you can type `console.log("Hello, World");` inside the repl.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I fixed it:

When you typed the command:

```
 node main.js
```

You accessed the node repl.

> The Node. js Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL) is an interactive shell that processes Node.js expressions.
> The shell reads JavaScript code the user enters, evaluates the result of interpreting the line of code, prints the result to the user, and loops until the user signals to quit."
> (Stack Abuse. September 18, 2019)

So basically, you were trying to run a JavaScript file from within a Javascript file.

The solution is to run the Javascript file before accessing the node.

So, you should exit the node with the following command:

```
.exit
```

Then, simply run the JavaScript file:

```
node filename.js
```

References:
DigitalOcean. September 18, 2019. Stack Abuse. How To Use the Node.js REPL. Retrieved from: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-node-js-repl

Answer (score -1):

```
node. js> $ node main.js 
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10) 
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:235:25) at bound (domain.js:287:14) 
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12) 
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:431:12) 
at emitOne (events.js:82:20) 
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7) 
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:212:10) 
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:551:8) 
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:828:14)
```

The stack trace you dumped in the comment indicate that you are using the module `readline`. As such, the code you posted is not the code you want us to debug.

You either aren't calling the right file, or not posting the right file.

EDIT:

What you said you have done is create a main file:

```
/home/jiju/test/main.js
```

Which contain:

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

But I think what you are calling is not the right file:

```
cd home/jiju
node main.js
```

Which contain (at least):

```
require('readline');
```

What you should do is ensure you are calling the right file, you can check that with the command cat:

```
cd /home/jiju
cat main.js #Will print "require('readline');"
```

And call the right file:

```
cd /home/jiju/test
cat main.js #Will print "console.log('HelloWorld')"
node main.js
```

Comment: tell me one thing i have a file main.js , with the console.log("Hello, World!") in one path ,I just opened node.js and typed   $ node main.js is it correct method i followed ?

Comment: I, like commenter above, don't understand why you are typing `$`. Is the console in the right folder/directory? I'm pretty sure if you type `cat main.js`, it is not `console.log('Hello World')` that will appear.

Comment: what u mean by  right folder/directory? ok iam just started to learn nodejs now can u please illustrate   to start a sample program ?

Comment: That is not a node.js problem, but you not executing the file you want. Please replace `node.js` by `cat` and show us what is printed.